# How do we find maximum value of $a$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For $n$ real numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ ( $n\geq 2$), consider

$\displaystyle a=\sin(x_1)\cos(x_2)+\sin(x_2)\cos(x_3)+\cdots+\sin(x_n)\cos(x_1).$

- How do we find maximum value of $a$?
- For what values of $x_1, x_2...., x_n$ is the maximum achieved?

I want to get help from you If that's possible.

Regards

Comment: When I see a function of several variables and an optimization problem, I think calculus.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Absoulety, sir. I've tried but couldn't work it out.

Comment: Also edited my question.

Comment: "Using symmetry" (not rigorous in any way), swaping the $\sin$ and $\cos$ gives us a permutation of the variables, adding the two equations we have a sum of $\sin(x_i+x_{i+1})$ which attains the maximum of $n$ when all variables are $\pi/4$. So we should expect the maximum would be $\frac n2$... assuming the symmetry doesn't break (which may not be true, just to give a thought)

Comment: @lEm I'm too sorry. I couldn't get what you mean. Could you please be more clear, sir?

Comment: It is not a proof. I was speculating the answer should be $\frac n2$ because of the symmetry of the function. Specifically, let $a=f(x_1,...,x_n)$, I observed that $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1},x_n)+f(x_n,x_{n-1},...,x_2,x_1)=\sin(x_1+x_2)+...+\sin(x_n+x_1)$ which attains the maximum of $n$. Since $f$ looks "pretty symmetric", I expect that all variables should be equal. So I guess the solution to be $\frac n2$

Comment: @lEm Oh, got it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By C-S and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sin{x_k}\cos{x_{k+1}}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2x_k\sum_{k=1}^n\cos^2x_k}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2x_k\left(n-\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2x_k\right)}\leq\frac{n}{2}.$$
The equality occurs for $x_k=\frac{\pi}{4}$, which says that $\frac{n}{2}$ is a maximal value.